# Difference between class and baseClass in Dojo? Or, when/how shall I use baseClass?

Tags: css, class, dojo

What is the *actual* difference between `class` and `baseClass` in `_WidgetBase`?
Both of them will add class(es) to the top node of a widget. baseClass is said to be used for "state changes" within the widget. But then, the Dojo tutorial on making widgets suggests people to use ${baseClass} in a template:

```
<div class="${baseClass}">
  <div class="${baseClass}Title" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick"></div>
</div>
```

I wonder if there is a point I am missing completely in every single one of my widgets.

Thanks!

Merc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the class `_CssStateMixin.js` which many dijit widgets use. The `class` attribute is simply a list of css classes to automatically apply to the widget's `domNode`.  `baseClass` on the other hand will be used to create "built in" css classes that are applied as the state of the widget changes (for instance to active, hovered, focused etc).

Take `dijit/form/Button`. Its baseClass is `dijitButton`.  When the button is hovered, the widget will automatically add the css class `dijitButtonHover`.  When the user no longer is hovering the button that css class is automatically removed.

If you changed the `baseClass` to something like `myButtonClass`, the hovered state class that is automatically applied would be `myButtonClassHover`.  This allows widget authors to easily write css rules for the various states of the widget without having to manually add classes or change styles within the widget itself.

Comment: Sorry for not accepting this sooner. I don't know how I missed it!